# Facebook sends very compressed image in messenger webhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

In my bot i use **Facebook Send Api**
I need get image send by user via facebook messenger 
(from *message.attachments[0].payload.url* )

But in web version and messenger app I gets VERY different compression

[Image in web version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guek0.jpg)

[Image in webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kNgk.jpg)

But it is very compressed and this is a big problem.
Is there any way to get an **original** or a better-quality image?

Comment: Pretty sure Facebook does this intentionally - Messenger is a mobile platform after all, so lots of users will be on limited data plans and/or have little bandwidth.

Comment: You are certainly right about mobile platform, but here the compressed image is sent to my server - the user's traffic is spent only when it is sent to platform, so not fully logic

Comment: Facebook answered to me https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1886073788317302/ - maybe someone will be useful